# TCP, UDP and HTTP servers inside docker stop immediately after starting the container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am to host TCP, UDP and HTTP servers, developed by Java, inside a java docker container.

All what I have in the `dockerfile` is a copy command for the server application and the `bash` files, which used to run the server/s.

However, **the servers are stopped some seconds after running the container?**

I use the following command for running the container:

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 2701:2701 --name app_test_con_1 app_test_img_1`

And this is the bootstrap command in the `dockerfile`:
`CMD ["/workspace/one_click.sh"]`

Is there any way to keep server running for ever? Since it does that if I run it with the same `.sh` files in the host OS; Of course as long as the terminal is not closed.

Comment: *Of course as long as the terminal is not closed*. A daemon must detach from the controlling terminal, right after startup.

Comment: but I ran the container with `-d` flag, as you can see in the command, and it does not work!

what I mean by that sentence is when I run it in the host not in the container.

Comment: What is the output of docker logs app_test_con_1? Maybe the application stops for some reasons.

Comment: I checked the logs, it works well without any errors!

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers will exit as soon as the process in the foreground completes. That means if your `one_click.sh` script does something like `service apache2 start` and then exits, the container will exit right away. Most of our Java images have some variant of the following to prevent this:

```
CMD service apache2 start && /bin/bash
```

The preferred way to use Docker is 1 process per container, if you're using it to run full VMs with services then you need to work around it.

Comment: Thank you @Kevan for your reply. I tried this way but its not working; its also shut down after running for seconds.

Comment: Whoops, looks like that was our old pattern for foreground containers. Try using `&& /usr/bin/tail -f /etc/hosts > /dev/null` instead of bash. I don't think containers in the background have stdin opened at all, making bash return immediately.